# Discord.js API latency (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws'))

Tags: node.js, discord.js

At this point, I have tried for hours to try to get the answer to this, but to no avail. So I am asking a question for this. I keep getting the same error (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ws')), and I'm not sure why. Below is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("ping")
        .setDescription("Gets bot and API latency"),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        interaction.reply({
            content:  `Latency is ${Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`,
            ephemeral: false,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you log `client` and show us the result?

Answer (score 0):

It's been months, but I had a similar issue — Gh0st is right, I'd just like to elaborate.

In `index.js`, or `bot.js`, or whatever your main file is called…

```js
// Declare a client!
const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});

// Then… whenever an interaction occurs…
client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {

    /* snip */

    try { // Pass the client (defined above) ↓ (interaction first! client second!)
        await command.execute(interaction, client);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({content: "There was an error while executing this command!", ephemeral: true});
    }
});
```

And then in your `ping.js` or whatever file it's called…

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
module.exports = {

    /* snip */

    // Now that you have the client ↓ (interaction first! client second!)
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        interaction.reply({
            // Now this should work, because client is defined ↓
            content:  `API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`,
            ephemeral: false,
        })
    }
}
```

The reason why you're getting the error of "ws" being undefined is because it doesn't seem like you're passing the client to the command. `execute()` is a function with two properties — `interaction` and `client` — you're missing the `client`.

That being said, I could be completely wrong. Being able to see your main file would help here. This is what happened with me, though.

Answer (score -1):

In the main bot.js file make sure your `interactionCreate` section looks like this:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)
        try {
            command.execute(client, interaction)

// The above line is what I'm referencing
// If you don't pass client through here, it can't be retrieved in the command

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            return interaction.reply({
                content: `There was an error while executing this command.`,
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Now I get ReferenceError: client is not defined (my bot.js does define client here though: const client = new Client({
 intents: [
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
 ]
});

Comment: Please post your client.on('interactionCreate' section in your original question, just add it to the bottom

also am I correct to assume that you have a line that looks like this: const { Client } = require('discord.js') and above the const client = new Client({...}) that you just posted.